# AngularJS template for form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, templates, angularjs-directive

I am writing an AngularJS application but I am struggling a bit making it modular.

I have a form which contains lots of inputs. For each one I have to repeat lots of code. Here is an example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3
            col-md-6 col-md-offset-3
            col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Device Category</span>
            <input 
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                autocomplete="off"
                ng-model="device.category"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3
            col-md-6 col-md-offset-3
            col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Device Template</span>
            <select 
                class="form-control"
                ng-model="device.characteristics"
                ng-change="copyDeviceTemplate(device)"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in templateDevices"
            >
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, lots of code is repeated. I therefore thought about creating my own directive. If successful, the two examples above would be written in HTML as follows:

```
<div device-input label="Device Category">
    <input 
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        autocomplete="off"
        ng-model="device.category"
    >
</div>

<div device-input label="Device Template">
    <select 
        class="form-control"
        ng-model="device.characteristics"
        ng-change="deepCopyDeviceTemplate(device)"
        ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in templateDevices"
    >
    </select>
</div>
```

The problem is that I cannot understand how to make such directive work. All I've got is this:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('deviceInput', [ function () {
    return function(scope, element, attributes) {

        var label = attributes['label'];

        var htmlText = '<div class="row">' + 
            '<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' + 
            '<div class="input-group">' + 
            '<span class="input-group-addon">' + label + '</span>' + 

            // Something here to add whatever is inside the <device-input> div

            '</div></div></div>';

        element.replaceWith( htmlText );
    };
}]);
```

This is what I was thinking to do, but I have no idea about how I can add whatever is inside the my device-input. Do you have any suggestion? Are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Enzey provided a good answer which I have tried to used. However, it does not completely work because the value of the input is not stored in the model. I guess it is a problem of scope binding... any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use transclusion to dynamically move the child elements of the directive into the template. Ideally I would put the HTML template into a separate file as well.

Try this:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive('deviceInput', [ function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        // Use scope true to make a copy of the parent scope, so you still have access to all parent scope values
        scope: true,
        template: function($element, $attrs) {
            var template = '<div class="row">' + 
                '<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">' + 
                '<div class="input-group">' + 
                // Probably eventually want to use {{label | translate}} to localize this value, then the the `label` on the directive would pass in the translation key instead of the value.
                '<span class="input-group-addon">{{label}}</span>' + 
                // Transclusion moves the child content of the directive here
                '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div></div></div>';
            return template;
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.label;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I'm curios to know why you added function inside template function & what it does?

Comment: Thank you Enzey!! I am trying to make it work, starting from your code but it does not. I believe one problem is that before `function(scope, element, attributes)` you need `return`. Still, it is not clear to me where I get the label from...

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `function(scope, element, attributes)` return `template`? I tried that as well, but looking in the Chrome console I see an error: "Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$compile/tplrtp0=deviceInput&p1= at Error (native)"

Comment: @pankajparkar you are right about that inner function of the template. That was a copy paste error and should not exist.

Comment: I thought that angular is introduced link inside template :p

Comment: Thank you, now it works! :) When you said that I should put the HTML template in a separate file, did you suggest using `templateUrl` or `ng-include` inside the var template?

Comment: `templateUrl`. If you use `ng-include` you get another level of DOM you don't need. This recommendation is because it is much easier to manage the HTML in a `.html` file than concatenating strings in Javascript.

Comment: Indeed, `templateUrl` allows to keep the code much more modular.The problem that I am finding with both approaches though is that with respect to the pedantic dummy version, using a directive the binding of the input is not stored. Following the example that I made, the text entered in the device category is not stored in device.category. Same thing for the select...